# SMO alternative for Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, smo

We use SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) in .Net code for programming all aspects of a Microsoft SQL Server database. Do we have any similar library for Oracle database that can be referred from C# code?